# IBM MQ Queue Manager channel SVRCONN does not starting

Tags: ibm-mq

I've created a queue manager named **TEST1** and in this queue manager i've created a channel named **TEST1** for server connection SVRCONN. My channel is created successfully but channel does not able to start.
[image]

When i tried to start the channel using MQ explorer is shows channel is starting but it doesn't start.

[image]

Kindly help me on this. I've also checks queue manager logs but doesn't found any useful.

Comment: It is an expected behavior. A SVRCONN channel will start when an application connects to queue manager using that channel.

Answer (score 1):

A SVRCONN only runs when you connect a client application to it. It will not go into Running state from a START CHANNEL command. The START CHANNEL command is only needed if it was STOPPED by another command and you needed to undo that and put it back into a state where it is able to run when an application connects.

To test this out, set an environment variable as follows:-

```
set MQSERVER=TEST/TCP/localhost(port-of-your-listener)
```

then run the following IBM Supplied sample application:-

```
amqsputc SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE TEST1
```

this application will wait for you to type in something to become the message text. While it is waiting, the application is connected to the queue manager and you should see the SVRCONN channel in Running status.

In order to see the channel in Running Status your application must stay connected. If you run the application, and let it complete, and thus close the connection, before you look at the channel status you will not see anything.

Try the example above just to prove to yourself that your SVRCONN does go into Running status, and then go back to your own application to see what the difference is. Is it short running? Is it definitely using the client connection and not local bindings?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've already connected to client application via IBM integration bus and Java. I put message on your mention queue through both applications but still channel status is inactive.

Comment: If your are running the apps on the same server as the queue manger then they may be connecting in a server bindings mode which means they wouldn't use the network or a channel,  if they are configured to use a channel,  they may be connecting and disconnecting before you check the channel status.

Comment: @AdilAbdullah Are you looking at the channel status while the application is active? The SVRCONN is only Running while the MQCONNection is active. Once the application disconnects, the SVRCONN stops. I have updated my answer thus.